# incoming ip address of client accessing a web service

Tags: wcf, iis

I have a web service (WCF) and configured it in IIS.  Now, is there any way I could see the client's ip addresses (incoming) which try to access the web service?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See Keyvan Nayyeri's excellent blog post on the topic:

[Detect Client IP in WCF 3.5](http://nayyeri.net/detect-client-ip-in-wcf-3-5)

It's **the** source on how to do this.

Comment: That is so much simpler than the hoops you had to jump through to do the same with remoting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/527676#527756