# Checking if a client WCF connection is from within the same LAN?

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-4.0

I've got a bunch of WCF webservices that are part of an internal application for a business. Right now everyone can access everything from anywhere, but now the owner wants only certain people to be able to connect from anywhere, and everyone else can only connect from within the office. I've added a "Can connect from outside of office" permission to each user, but I can't find a reliable way to check of the connection is coming from within the office local network.

I feel like any solution I'd make would be hack-ish at best, does anyone know of a good way to check if a WCF connection is coming from within the same LAN or IP?

Comment: These posts (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93162/obtaining-client-ip-address-in-wcf-3-0 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662399/incoming-ip-address-of-client-accessing-a-web-service) might help.

Comment: can you  give us  an idea on how your front end is created