# How to know which client called method in .NET Remoting?

Tags: c#, .net, remoting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Identifying the client during a .NET remoting invocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527676/identifying-the-client-during-a-net-remoting-invocation)

I have a client/server app, in which server-side part publishes static object in that way:

```
RemotingServices.Marshal(rem, "testRemoteObject");
```

Many client-side parts connect to It simultaneously through:

```
TestInterface remote = (TestInterface)RemotingServices.Connect(typeof(TestInterface), 
            "tcp://localhost:4500/testRemoteObject");
```

All is working fine, but I need determine on server-side, which client calls method, like this:

```
public void PrintMsg(string msg)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Message from client: " + msg);
}
```

I see one path: each client sends its id as method argument, but in this case clients may send id of another client. How can I do what I want?

Comment: if it's not Id, how do you distinguish clients?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using the remoting pattern where an object is created for each client, in which case you can use some magic (that I forget OTOH) to store the client in a field/property, I do not believe there is a way.