# .Net remoting: Know in a service if the call have been made locally or remotely?

Tags: c#, ipc, remoting, .net-remoting, tcpchannel

I currently have a .Net remoting service that can be accessed by different ways:

- Locally through an IPC channel
- Remotely through a TCP channel
- Locally  through a TCP channel

I need to known, in one of my service method, if the call has been made locally or remotely(depending on a licence, I've to send smaller data remotely).

I can't find a way to find this.

I've already a custom `IServerChannelSink`, I thought that I can detect which type of channel is used of this call, and if it's a TCP one, check it's IP, but I can't find how.

Do you have any idea about how to check if we have a local call or not?

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/527756/2072213) shows how to identify the client using its IP address. As you've already got a custom server channel sink it should be fairly straight forward.

Comment: Yeah, but in the case of a local IPC channel, how to know that we are in the case of the IPC channel?

Comment: @J4N If an IPC channel is used then `CallContext.GetData("ClientIPAddress")` will return null.

Comment: Yeah right(in fact it's the `requestHeaders[CommonTransportKeys.IPAddress]` that is null, but I see, I can manage that like this, thank you!

Comment: @J4N Or you could check for a null IP address in the `ClientIPServerSink` `AsyncProcessResponse` and `ProcessMessage` methods and do something like `CallContext.SetData("ClientIPAddress", "IPC");`.

Comment: Yes, it was what I was meaning